# Request to another MVC action from within an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, httpclient

I have the following code:

```
var url = Url.Action("JobDetailsPDF", "PdfController", new { orderid = model.OrderId }, Request.Url.Scheme);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", Request.Headers["Cookie"]);

var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

The Authorize attribute seems to keep redirecting the request to the login screen, even though the auth cookies are added to the request.

Why am I unable to send cookies to another action within the same site and if I am able to, why is the authorize attribute redirecting the request when the cookies are added?

Thanks

Comment: You should move the logic in the action you are trying to call into it's own class and use that in any action method that you need. That way you are not needlessly calling it via an HTTP request (and all the overhead that will incur)

Answer (score 2):

That's usually bad idea to make HTTP request from backend app to the same backend app.

You can move the logic from JobDetailsPDF action under PdfController to some common class that can be used from both places: JobDetailsPDF and your current code location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd started the refactor when I started to encounter issues, but i wanted to understand why sending cookies from one action to the next wasn't working. Do you happen to know?

Comment: First request comes from client browser (with auth cookies in it) while second request is done by your backend server which does not have auth cookies in it.

Comment: Won't adding the cookies from the incoming request include the auth cookie?

Comment: You can do that and it should work but overall solution design looks very weird with lots of overhead.